# Azure Functions, Event Hub Trigger: The Listener Was Unable To Start

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have a Functionapp running with an Event Hub Trigger function. It is present in three environments, and has worked without a problem for a long time. AlwaysOn is enabled in all environments.

Suddenly, one environment, let's call it DEV, is throwing an error from the function app:

`The listener for function 'EventHubTriggerFunction' was unable to start.`

Drilling down into the exception, I can see the following:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException:
Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.EventProcessorConfigurationException:
...
Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager+<GetPartitionIdsAsync>d__6.MoveNext:
...
```

Sometimes, I can see the exception message presents itself as `"The listener for function 'EventHubTriggerFunction' was unable to start. Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds No such host is known."`

A type System.Net.Sockets.Exception is persisting. Other threads have said to upgrade the EventHubs.Processor package to 4.2.0 at least and it will fix the issue, that did not fix the issue.

What is even more weird is that at some points in the day, requests do actually come through, and the EventHubTrigger runs successfully. Most of the time though, the listener is unable to start.

This error is not present in the other environments, although the setup is the same.

I've confirmed that the EventHubConnectionSetting is valid and correct by comparing it with the listen policy in the relevant event hub.

I've tried restarting the functionapp.

When trying to run the EventHubTrigger locally, it also works without this error.

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: The error indicates that DNS lookup failed and the host identified by your connection string is unknown.  Are you storing your connection string in JSON or another encoded format?   Sometimes things like embedded quotes can cause issues with parsing and malform the host.

Comment: @JesseSquire I am storing the connecting string in a Key Vault as a secret, just as normal text. The Function app has a Key Vault Reference set in its App Settings in order to be able to access the connection string secret.

Comment: Can you post the connection string, with the sensitive parts redacted?  Alternatively, you may want to try parsing with the `EventHubsConnectionStringProperties` class and verifying that you see each property populated with what you expect.

Comment: @JesseSquire I tried a test by directly setting the EventHubConnectionSetting app setting as the plain connection string copied straight from the relevant event hub. It did not fix the issue, the listener is still unable to start. The connection string is in this form: Endpoint=sb://my-eventhub-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=listenPolicy;SharedAccessKey=<accessKey>;EntityPath=<eventHubName>

Comment: Format looks correct.   If you attempt to `nslookup` (or similar) the namespace endpoint, does it resolve?

Comment: If it's running in some environments and failing for others, it sounds like an issue with the host network.   If this is running in Azure, I'd strongly suggest opening a support request.

Comment: @JesseSquire when using `nslookup` for the namespace endpoint, it does resolve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252695/discussion-between-mkcoding-and-jesse-squire).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause ended up being an Azure networking issue.

My Azure infra was setup with private endpoints and VNET Integration. In terms of the latter, the setting `Route All` was set to `Enabled`, via the `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` app setting being set to `1` during deployment.

It's not clear why suddenly the listener was unable to start, but removing the app setting and disabling the `Route All` allowed the listener to start normally, again.

I suspect that because of this unknown occurrence, the `EventHubConnectionAppSetting` was not able to be read/binded to.

My traffic from function app to function app within the same network was unaffected by this change.